# Change run time compile version of php engine

Tags: php

Is there is any way to do that
I have php 5 version but I want to compile my code in php 4

Comment: "Compile" and "PHP" in the same sentence?

Comment: Do you mean you have code written for PHP5 and it needs to *run* on a PHP4 server?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to use PHP 5 to check compatibility with PHP 4 (I'm assuming that is what you want to do).

PHP also does not have a "compiler" per-se. It generates an intermediary opcode representation (which can be stored by various cachers for extra speed), but it is not possible to take said opcode representation and store it to then run it on various different PHP versions.